# .NETStandard Library nuget package - cannot install on standard project

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-core

I have .NET Core project with the following `project.json`:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postcompile": [
      "dotnet pack --no-build --configuration %compile:Configuration%"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have created nuget package (see `postcompile` above)  and published in nuget.

Then I've created standard 4.6.2  library, but cannot install package - there is error that package doesn't contain valid assemblies for target .NET Framework 4.6.2.

How should I prepare nuget package to make it available in standard library? I thiough that target NETStandard is valid for both - core and standard projects.

Comment: nope. you have to add the target-framework-support in your nuget package. add net462 into your project.json

Comment: Is it possible to it with postcompile? In docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-pack there is no such an option.

Comment: add the targetframework net462 into the project.json . with postcompile it'snot possible. your package will get the support after adding the target-framework. (there are code/library-differences between net462 and netstandard1.6)

Comment: see my answere as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to add support for .Net Framework 4.6.2 with adding "net462" to your project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    },
    "net462": {
        "dependencies" : {
            "System.Runtime": "4.0.20.0" // you may have to add this
            // add here your dependencies
        }
    }
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postcompile": [
      "dotnet pack --no-build --configuration %compile:Configuration%"
    ]
  }
}
```

[see also my project.json on github with a few supported frameworks](https://github.com/matthiasburger/IronSphere/blob/master/IronSphere.Extensions/project.json)

Answer (score 5):

If you check the compatibility matrix for .Net Standard it looks like .Net 4.6.2 only supports NetStandard 1.5. Under frameworks you are targeting 1.6 that is marked for vNext.

[See here for the compatibility matrix to know what version you should target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library)

So in other words if you change your config to the following you should be able to reference the library freely:

```
"frameworks": 
{
    "netstandard1.5": {}
}
```

You don't need to add another framework type like suggested in another answer since 4.6.2 should be able to reference a 1.5 Standard.

Comment: The other big gotcha that relates to this, if you are packaging your own nuget packages be careful of the "global" nuget cache under your users folder, if you accidentally end up with a legacy packages that are configured incorrectly it can leave you scratching your head for a while with only obtuse errors from VS...